# Complete on function name of called, non-existent function

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Usually, I create the called function first and then intellisense will complete on the function name so I do not have to spell it out.

Sometimes, I write code in the reverse order so that I am calling a function that does not exist (resulting in resharper presenting the code in red) and afterwards writing the called function.

Can I have intellisense complete on that as well? Or is there a word completion of another kind that I can use?

## case 1

step 1

```
private void func1()
{
}

private void foo()
{
}
```

step 2

```
private void func1()
{
  foo();
}

private void foo()
{
}
```

(when starting to write `foo` in step 2, it is completed).

## case 2

step 1

```
private void func1()
{
  foo();
}
```

step 2

```
private void func1()
{
  foo();
}

private void foo()
{
}
```

(when starting to write `foo` in step 2, it is not completed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use quick actions in VS 2015 to create function definitions for you.

[A short MSDN article on quick actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872466.aspx)